# update to hook causes Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook for the `use-debounce` package that looks takes in a state and causes a delay to return the setstate.  There was recently a change to to the module `breaking change: Now useDebouncedCallback returns an object instead of array:` [located here under 5.0.0](https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) And I simply don't understand the simple update my code needs in order to work again

The Hook

```
export default (initialState, durationInMs = 200, options = {}) => {
  const [internalState, setInternalState] = useState(initialState);

  const [debouncedSetter] = useDebouncedCallback(
    setInternalState,
    durationInMs,
    options
  );
  return [internalState, debouncedSetter];
};
```

How I call the hook inside my component

```
 const [searchText, setSearchText] = useDebouncedState("", 900, {
   maxWait: 1000,
 });
 setSearchText(searchText);
```

The error i get is `TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.` because its now returning an object. What do I do to modify my code to handle the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking into the docs it seems that you should change:

```
const [debouncedSetter] = useDebouncedCallback(setInternalState, durationInMs, options);
```

with

```
const {callback: debouncedSetter} = useDebouncedCallback(setInternalState, durationInMs, options);
```

Given an explanation in the release notes:

```
Old:

const [debouncedCallback, cancelDebouncedCallback, callPending] = useDebouncedCallback(/*...*/);

New:

const debounced = useDebouncedCallback(/*...*/);
/**
 * debounced: {
 *   callback: (...args: T) => unknown, which is debouncedCallback
 *   cancel: () => void, which is cancelDebouncedCallback
 *   flush: () => void, which is callPending
 *   pending: () => boolean, which is a new function
 * }
 */
```

Comment: I guess i was missing the callback: portion of that.